# Cannot resolve symbol 'ImageView2'

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, ontouchlistener

I am trying to create an ImageView in a Fragment which will refer to the ImageView element which I have created in the XML for the Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        final View c = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_source, container, false);

        ImageView view = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        return c;

    }
```

But although I thought it would work it cannot resolve 'ImageView3'

Comment: I have already tried that but it makes no diffrence

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble, I found it, my id was 'imageView3' in my xml and in my class I had written 'ImageView3'. I Guess I should just go to sleep and call it a day

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`(ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);`

use

`(ImageView) c.findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your xml for activity_source (you didnt post it), I think

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
```

should be

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) c.findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
```